# How can I Open Multiple Popups in Leaflet Marker at a time

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, leaflet.markercluster

Map` like this:

```
L.Map = L.Map.extend({
openPopup: function(popup) {
this._popup = popup;
        return this.addLayer(popup).fire('popupopen', {
            popup: this._popup
        });
    }
});
```

But I am using leaflet. Is there anyway to extent like so that i can prevent closing my marker popup?

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = constant.accessToken;
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', {zoomControl: true});
```

Answer (score 19):

Update Dec 2017
Leaflet [popup](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#popup) options have been extended to include `{ autoClose: false }` which has the required effect :

```js
 var my_marker = L.marker([my_lat, my_lng], {icon: my_icon})
                  .addTo(map)
                  .bindPopup('My Popup HTML', {closeOnClick: false, autoClose: false});
```

Answer (score 6):

Let me quote the [Leaflet documentation on `L.Popup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#popup):

> Used to open popups in certain places of the map. Use `Map.openPopup` to open popups while making sure that only one popup is open at one time (recommended for usability), or use `Map.addLayer` to open as many as you want.

In order to open several popups, instantiate them using `L.popup(latlng, options)`, then `.addTo(map)` them.

Answer (score 0):

Define an array:

```
let map=L.map('mymap');
...    
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

...

var marker=[];
marker[0]= L.marker([latitud1,longitud1]).addTo(map).bindPopup('Hola 0',{autoClose: false, closeOnClick: false});
marker[1]= L.marker([latitud2,longitud2]).addTo(map).bindPopup('Hola 1',{autoClose: false, closeOnClick: false});
```

To put on the map:

```
marker.forEach(function(marker) {
       markers.addLayer(marker);
       map.addLayer(markers);
});
```

Show the popup for only one:

```
var curPos = marker[0].getLatLng();
map.setView(new L.LatLng(curPos.lat,curPos.lng), 13);
marker[0].openPopup();
```

Show all popups:

```
marker.forEach(function(marker) {
     var popup = marker.getPopup();
     marker.bindPopup(popup.getContent()).openPopup();
 });
```

Close all popups:

```
 map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
      layer.closePopup();
  });
```